# Как отключить родной datepicker в firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox

Использую datepicker от Jquery. В браузере firefox При нажатии на `<input type="date">` отражается сразу два datepicker:

1. Родной от firefox
2. Подключенный через Jquery

Каким образом можно отключить родной от firexox?

При этом поменять input type на text что-то другое нельзя.

Comment: поменять  нельзя в верстке? или вообще? нельзя просто сделать `$("#input").attr('type', 'text').datepicker()` ?

Comment: @teran Нужно понять, как это отключается при ```<input type="date">``` )

Comment: в хроме можно стилями убрать, но в ФФ похоже никак. хотя можете сделать `preventDefault` в событии клика